# What is the best way to override a function in an aikau widget in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise, aikau

I am using Alfresco 6.2 Enterprise version. I have a requirement which calls for a couple of modifications in https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfSearchList.js_.html module.

1. What is the best approach to override the `onScopeSelection` function?
2. Is there a way I can modify `searchPayload` to include a new attribute?

I have gone through Alfresco documentation and couldn not figure out what's the best way to override an existing aikau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to override a function in Aikau is typically to extend the widget module in question and use module "class hierarchy" to override the function inherited from the AlfSearchList. The OOTBee Support Tools project has an example of a [module extending `AlfList` and overriding its `onDataLoadSuccess`](https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools/blob/master/share/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/ootbee-support-tools/list/LogList.js#L171) function. Once you have your own custom module, you can use a Surf Extension Module to customise the JSON model of the faceted search page to change the [name of the module used for the search list](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/pages/faceted-search/faceted-search.get.js#L575) to yours.

Unfortunately there is no other way to modify the `searchPayload` other than overriding the `loadData` function as well. And then the added attribute would not do anything unless you also override the [SearchService's `onSearchRequest`](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/SearchService.js.html#line228) function and used your custom service instead of the [default](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/pages/faceted-search/faceted-search.get.js#L575) by again modifying the JSON model of the page.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an additional search scope. I have tried to override the `rootNode` with a particular nodeRef value if my custom scope is the `selectedScope` in `AlfSearchList`.  It has no effect though. Any ideas what this could be?